# Extendscript - Adobe Illustrator - Ellipse not in right location

Tags: javascript, adobe-illustrator, extendscript

I'm trying to do something that seems simple, but not sure how it's not working.  I have a map layer and I'm trying to draw circles via Extendscript.  I'm trying to test just by trying to draw a simple circle at point 100,100 (I assume top left of map is 0,0), but when I execute it, the circle appears way further down than it should be (seems close to 200,700).  Below is my code I'm using...

```
var dotRadius = 8.136 / 2;
var testDOT = mapLayer.pathItems.ellipse(100, 100, dotRadius*2, dotRadius*2, false, false);
testDOT.strokeWidth = 0.25;
testDOT.strokeColor = getColor("MAROON"); // defined above
testDOT.fillColor = getColor("MAROON");
```

the getColor just creates a CYMK Color object.  Can anyone give me a clue on why the 100,100 point is not where I expect it to be?

TIA!

Comment: A screenshot wouldn't hurt. With the rulers.

Comment: [link](https://photos.app.goo.gl/VPSVGQ2yicKaD4b79) here is a screenshot... i changed the rulers to show points

Comment: Could you click two times on the left-top corner of the window (to reset a zero point) and show how the coordinates look like in the Transform panel? https://imgur.com/4gz8hAr.png

Comment: I double clicked, but didn't seem like it does anything.  Here is the transformation screenshot [link](https://photos.app.goo.gl/nUCmGJKAtcQ3DM2d6)

Comment: Also, just FYI, my script loads a template and then adds DOTs.... is there a script way to "reset zero point"?

Comment: I found the zeroPath/pageOrigin properties.  I tried setting it to [0,0], but nothing has changed.

Comment: Alas, can't reproduce your error. I just created a new file and run the code. Here is result (red arrow) https://imgur.com/ttJdUng You say you have another results (blue arrow). I see no reason for such result. Probably something is broken in your document. If you share your file I can try to figure out.

Comment: I found the issue.... the 100,100 point is using the coordinates of the Artboard (there are 2 of them)... here is a screenshot [link](https://photos.app.goo.gl/bRHSSTnJk33WmPWEA).  notice the Y axis starts from bottom and X axis starts to left (but not flush with the layer), now to find a way to work with that or have someone redo the template i'm using.

Comment: You can reset or ignore the relative artboard coordinate system. I've posted examples in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case, it looks like your script used the 'relative' coordinate system (relative to zero point of current artboard).

To made it to use 'absolute' coordinates (relative to the top-left corner of the first artboard for a new document) you can add this line at the start of your script:

```
app.coordinateSystem = CoordinateSystem.DOCUMENTCOORDINATESYSTEM;
```

Or you can use the 'relative' coordinate system:

```
app.coordinateSystem = CoordinateSystem.ARTBOARDCOORDINATESYSTEM;
```

In this case you can move zero point of any artboard with this commands:

```
var doc = app.activeDocument;
doc.artboards[0].rulerOrigin = [0,0];
doc.artboards[1].rulerOrigin = [200,700];
// etc
```

Comment: Thank you again.... after moving that zero-point, everything was being put in the proper place.